# How to sort Dictionary like this [[Strnig : AnyOBject]]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sorting, dictionary

I've got this kind of Dictionary:

```
var data = [[String : AnyObject]]()

data = [["name" : "Alex", "time" : 11.1], ["name" : "Igor", "time" : 2.0], ["name: Tomas" : "time" : 8.88]]
```

and now I would like to sort it by best time. I know how to do it in simple Array, but in this Dictionary I have a problem. Can somebody help me in it?

Comment: Thx, I found answer in you hint.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
data.sortInPlace { (obj1, obj2) -> Bool in
    guard let time1 = obj1["time"] as? Float else {return false}
    guard let time2 = obj2["time"] as? Float else {return false}
    return time1 < time2
}
```